# TranslationJobInstantiated event in Tridion Web 8.5

Tags: web8.5, event-system, translation-manager

I cannot seem to find the `TranslationJobInstantiated` event in the new `Tridion.TranslationManager.V2.EventSystem.Events` namespace. We were using the deprecated plugin system to automatically set entries in the jobs for the customer but trying to be supportable with the new version. `ITranslationJobLoadEventArgs` does not seem to be fired for a new job created in the interface that has not been saved yet. Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, unfortunately ITranslationJobLoadEventArgs does not fire for new job, so we do not have event for newly created job. This is our oversight and need to be added back to product.

But for now can you use Save event or is it changes that you do have to be added before user see job?

Comment: We were adding things before the user sees the job. We will forgo this for now, notify the users and use some JavaScript. @yuri-bondarchuk, put this request on the ideas page to be looked at for the next release?

Comment: We already created story for next release.